# Short Handing path name

Tags: c#

Currently I have as my file path

```
 @"S:\Temporary Shared Space\Project\Boyscout3\Data\full_pack.txt"
```

I want it to be just "full_pack.txt".

I tried this code on the bottom but it appears to not be working for me:

If someone could please help I would appreciate it.

```
string fileName =@"S:\Temporary Shared Space\Project\Boyscout\Data\full_pack.txt";
string path = "full_pack.txt";
string result;
result = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", fileName, result);

result = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", path, result);

//filename shorter for den1
string fileName1 =@"S:\Temporary Shared Space\Project\Boyscout3\Data\den1.txt";
string path1 = "den1.txt";
string result1;

result1 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName1);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", fileName1, result1);

result1 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path1);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", path1, result1);

//Making a list for full_pack
List<string> listFullPack = new List<string>();
string line;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("full_pack.txt");//this is where things don't work. 
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)////When the full address is in, the code works, 
{                            //but when I replace it with full_pack.txt, 
    listFullPack.Add(line); //it can't find the file.
}
sr.Close();
```

Comment: are you familiar with the `File.IO` methods for example `GetFileName` have you looked at any of the `System.IO` methods on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

The line `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("full_pack.txt");` will look in the executable directory for this file.  You need top append the full path to the file name.

You are using the wrong method from the library.

Try `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` and see the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I tried following the docs, however when I change the address when using streamreader, I get the FileNotFoundException

Comment: I think you need to post more code and expand your question.

Comment: I just updated the question. Does this help?